# SQL server logic for fetching data from the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

"Need to display all items linked to the parent category id=1 As per the table, It should fetch:Big Machine, Computer, CPU Cabinet, Hard Disk and Magnetic Disk. But by the logic that is written it is not fetching all the records. Plz help.."

```
  create table ItemSpares
  (
        ItemName varchar(20),
        ItemID int,
        ParentCategoryID int
  )

  insert into ItemSpares (ItemName,ItemID,ParentCategoryID)
  select 'Big Machine', 1 , NULL UNION ALL
  select 'Computer', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  select 'CPU Cabinet', 3, 2 UNION ALL
  select 'Hard Disk', 4, 3 UNION ALL
  select 'Magnetic Disk',5,4 UNION ALL
  select 'Another Big Machine',6, NULL
```

Comment: i am not able to find the logic.. apart frm this i couldnt do anything much :select itemname, itemid from ItemSpares where ParentCategoryID =1 or ItemID=1

Comment: According to your inserted data, only "Computer" has  a parent category equal to 1

Comment: as u can see from the items that magnetic disk is a sub category of hard disk, hard disk is the sub category of cpu cabinet, cpu cabinet is the sub category of computer and finally computer is sub category of big machine. so all these items are linked to the super parent-big machine(having item id as 1). therefore i need to fetch all records linked to item id as 1. hope i could make it more clear...

Comment: It should fetch:Big Machine, Computer, CPU Cabinet, Hard Disk and Magnetic Disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a hierarchical SQL query, took a while to figure out but try this:

```
with BigComputerList (ItemName, ItemID, ParentCategoryID, Level) 
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ItemName, e.ItemID, e.ParentCategoryID,
        0 AS Level
    FROM ItemSpares AS e
    WHERE ItemID = 1
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ItemName, e.ItemID, e.ParentCategoryID,
        Level + 1
    FROM ItemSpares AS e    
    INNER JOIN BigComputerList AS d
        ON e.ParentCategoryId = d.ItemID
)

Select * From BigComputerList
```

I would highly recommend reading this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you want to understand what the query is doing.

Comment: Nono actually it should fetch all the items which are linked to parent categoryid 1 i.e.  It should fetch:Big Machine, Computer, CPU Cabinet, Hard Disk and Magnetic Disk

Comment: Are you sure your insert statement is correct? That is a pretty unusual way to do an insert (I'd probably just do them separately). The parent ID's are also going up kind of sequentially i.e. null,1,2,3,4,null?

Comment: ya insert statement is correct. as u can see from the items that magnetic disk is a sub category of hard disk, hard disk  is the sub category of cpu cabinet, cpu cabinet is the sub category of computer and finally computer is sub category of big machine. so all these items are linked to the super parent-big machine(having item id as 1). therefore i need to fetch all records linked to item id as 1. hope i could make it more clear...

Comment: u can execute the script in sql server and check the data by yourself

Comment: It should fetch:Big Machine, Computer, CPU Cabinet, Hard Disk and Magnetic Disk.

Comment: Has this answered your question? I'm just curious as it took me a while to work it out...